# Semilogy interpolation; get x from y

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data:

```
x = [0, 2, 4, 8, 30]
y = [1.2e-3, 3.5e-4, 5.1e-5, 1.6e-5, 2e-7]
```

I'm trying to interpolate to get y from a given x value.

When plotted the data looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.semilogy(x, y, 'o-')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

So say I'm interested in finding what value of x is for a y value of 3e-5.

I can get the x value of a given y by:

```
z = np.linspace(0, 30, 10000)
logy = np.log10(y)
yy = np.power(10.0, np.interp(z, x, logy))
z[np.isclose(3.5e-5, yy, atol=1e-8)]
```

Out:

```
array([5.29852985])
```

But I have to adjust the `atol` if I change the value to get a single match and also have to create a load more data points to get the resolution.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to find the `x_f` corresponding to `y_f`. Assuming the entries in your original list `y` are in strictly decreasing order and the entries in x are increasing, you find the first entry in `y` that is less than or equal to your `y_0`. Say it is the one at index `i`, so the x,y tuples that make up your the relevant linear function from your piecewise partition will be (x[i-1],y[i-1]) and (x[i], y[i]).
Using the formula for the line given two points on the line we can get `x_f`:

```
x_f = x[i-1] + (x[i]-x[i-1])/(y[i]-y[i-1])*(y_f-y[i-1])
```

Comment: Thanks, could you expand your answer? What do you get when you try this?